# Code advice needed | Inefficient Solution - Advent of Code 2021, Day 3, Part 1

Tags: python

My code is working but it is extremely long. So, I guess there is a way to make it shorter/more efficient.

The problem solved here is from Advent of Code 2021, Day 3, Part 1: https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3

```
binary_list = open("data.txt").read().split("\n")

counter_1st_bit_0 = 0
counter_1st_bit_1 = 0

counter_2nd_bit_0 = 0
counter_2nd_bit_1 = 0

counter_3rd_bit_0 = 0
counter_3rd_bit_1 = 0

counter_4th_bit_0 = 0
counter_4th_bit_1 = 0

counter_5th_bit_0 = 0
counter_5th_bit_1 = 0

counter_6th_bit_0 = 0
counter_6th_bit_1 = 0

counter_7th_bit_0 = 0
counter_7th_bit_1 = 0

counter_8th_bit_0 = 0
counter_8th_bit_1 = 0

counter_9th_bit_0 = 0
counter_9th_bit_1 = 0

counter_10th_bit_0 = 0
counter_10th_bit_1 = 0

counter_11th_bit_0 = 0
counter_11th_bit_1 = 0

counter_12th_bit_0 = 0
counter_12th_bit_1 = 0


gamma_rate_queue = []
epsilon_rate_queue = []


for i in range(0, len(binary_list), 1):
  for j in range(0, len(binary_list[i]), 1):

    if binary_list[i][0] == "0":
      counter_1st_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][0] == "1":
      counter_1st_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][1] == "0":
      counter_2nd_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][1] == "1":
      counter_2nd_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][2] == "0":
      counter_3rd_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][2] == "1":
      counter_3rd_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][3] == "0":
      counter_4th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][3] == "1":
      counter_4th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][4] == "0":
      counter_5th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][4] == "1":
      counter_5th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][5] == "0":
      counter_6th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][5] == "1":
      counter_6th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][6] == "0":
      counter_7th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][6] == "1":
      counter_7th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][7] == "0":
      counter_8th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][7] == "1":
      counter_8th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][8] == "0":
      counter_9th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][8] == "1":
      counter_9th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][9] == "0":
      counter_10th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][9] == "1":
      counter_10th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][10] == "0":
      counter_11th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][10] == "1":
      counter_11th_bit_1 += 1

    if binary_list[i][11] == "0":
      counter_12th_bit_0 += 1
    elif binary_list[i][11] == "1":
      counter_12th_bit_1 += 1


def gamma_rate_finder():

  if counter_1st_bit_0 > counter_1st_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_1st_bit_0 < counter_1st_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_2nd_bit_0 > counter_2nd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_2nd_bit_0 < counter_2nd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_3rd_bit_0 > counter_3rd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_3rd_bit_0 < counter_3rd_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_4th_bit_0 > counter_4th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_4th_bit_0 < counter_4th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_5th_bit_0 > counter_5th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_5th_bit_0 < counter_5th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_6th_bit_0 > counter_6th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_6th_bit_0 < counter_6th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_7th_bit_0 > counter_7th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_7th_bit_0 < counter_7th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_8th_bit_0 > counter_8th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_8th_bit_0 < counter_8th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_9th_bit_0 > counter_9th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_9th_bit_0 < counter_9th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_10th_bit_0 > counter_10th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_10th_bit_0 < counter_10th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_11th_bit_0 > counter_11th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_11th_bit_0 < counter_11th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_12th_bit_0 > counter_12th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_12th_bit_0 < counter_12th_bit_1:
    gamma_rate_queue.append('1')

  gamma_rate = ''.join(gamma_rate_queue)

  return gamma_rate


def epsilon_rate_finder():

  if counter_1st_bit_0 < counter_1st_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_1st_bit_0 > counter_1st_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_2nd_bit_0 < counter_2nd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_2nd_bit_0 > counter_2nd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_3rd_bit_0 < counter_3rd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_3rd_bit_0 > counter_3rd_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_4th_bit_0 < counter_4th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_4th_bit_0 > counter_4th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_5th_bit_0 < counter_5th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_5th_bit_0 > counter_5th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_6th_bit_0 < counter_6th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_6th_bit_0 > counter_6th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_7th_bit_0 < counter_7th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_7th_bit_0 > counter_7th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_8th_bit_0 < counter_8th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_8th_bit_0 > counter_8th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_9th_bit_0 < counter_9th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_9th_bit_0 > counter_9th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_10th_bit_0 < counter_10th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_10th_bit_0 > counter_10th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_11th_bit_0 < counter_11th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_11th_bit_0 > counter_11th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  if counter_12th_bit_0 < counter_12th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('0')
  elif counter_12th_bit_0 > counter_12th_bit_1:
    epsilon_rate_queue.append('1')

  epsilon_rate = ''.join(epsilon_rate_queue)

  return epsilon_rate


binary_gamma_rate = gamma_rate_finder()
binary_epsilon_rate = epsilon_rate_finder()


def Binary_to_DecimalValue(n):
  b_num = list(n)
  value = 0
  for i in range(len(b_num)):
      digit = b_num.pop()
      if digit == '1':
          value = value + pow(2, i)
  return value


gamma_rate = Binary_to_DecimalValue(binary_gamma_rate)
epsilon_rate = Binary_to_DecimalValue(binary_epsilon_rate)


PowerConsumption = gamma_rate * epsilon_rate

print("Gamma rate is: {} | {}".format(gamma_rate, binary_gamma_rate) + "\n" + "Epsilon rate is: {} | {}".format(epsilon_rate, binary_epsilon_rate) + "\n" + "The Power Consumption is: {}".format(PowerConsumption))
```

Any advice about my code would be helpful, I guess there is a way to replace lists here and to make the loops and functions more efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: This is better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I reposted this question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270682/code-advice-needed-inefficient-solution-advent-of-code-2021-day-3-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your right, especially your loops can be made much simpler and shorter.
first you should get rid of all those variables and loop though the strings as well.
Second you don't have to write the binary to decimal function yourself, you can use the built in `int(num, 2)`.
If you apply just that you can already make your code much more compact.

I made a little sample if you need inspiration, but don't read any further if you want to figure it out yourself.

this is about how i would aproach this:

```
binary_list = open("data.txt").read().split("\n")

gamma_rate = ""
# go through all indexes of the binary strings (1-5)
for i in range(len(binary_list[0])):
    c = 0
    # go through all the binary strings
    for part in binary_list:
        # count the 1's
        if part[i] == "1": c += 1
    # if more than half were 1's record 1 else 0
    if c > len(binary_list)/2: gamma_rate += "1"
    else: gamma_rate += "0"
    c = 0

# change 1's to 0 for epsilan rate
epsilon_rate = "".join(["0" if i == "1" else "1" for i in gamma_rate])
power_consumtion = int(gamma_rate, 2) * int(epsilon_rate, 2)

print("Gamma rate is: {} | {} \nEpsilon rate is: {} | {} \nThe Power Consumption is: {}".format(gamma_rate, int(gamma_rate, 2), epsilon_rate, int(epsilon_rate, 2), power_consumtion))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @cyFx made some good points there already.
This is how I approached this challenge:

```py
with open("day3-input1.txt", 'r') as file:
  inputs = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in file.readlines()]

cols_num = len(inputs[0])
rows_num = len(inputs)
print("Cols:", cols_num, "Rows:", rows_num)

import numpy as np

diagnostic_data = np.asarray(
  [int(cell) for row in inputs for cell in row]
).reshape(rows_num, cols_num)

gamma = ''
for i in range(cols_num):
    gamma += '1' if diagnostic_data[:,i].sum() > rows_num/2 else '0'
# epsilon is basically an inverted gamma
epsilon = ''.join(['0' if v == '1' else '1' for v in gamma]) 
print("  gamma: ", gamma)
print("epsilon: ", epsilon)

# binary->int conversion and multiple for final score
print(int(gamma, 2) * int(epsilon, 2))
```